# uipopovercontroller animation like in iPad Maps.app

Tags: ipad, animation, maps, uipopovercontroller

I'm wondering how to make the same popover animation as in Maps.app on iPad. It seems the popover grows in 2-directions at the same time.

Thanks in advance.